# oxford dictionary API with POST MAN

Tags: api, postman

Where Do I Send My `Application ID` and `Application Keys` in `POST MAN` to Access `Oxford Dictionary API`
I Have tried `Api Key` In POST MAN but error `Authentication parameters missing`

https://developer.oxforddictionaries.com/documentation

https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/authorization/

Comment: Can you update the question with a link to the documentation.

Comment: @DannyDainton done

Comment: If this the same one I'm thinking of - Add the `app_id` and `app_key` as request headers, using the respective values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `app_id` and `app_key` as request headers, using your respective values.

[image]

More about where those header can be added:

https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/requests/#configuring-request-headers